# MySqlDataAdapter SQL syntax usage

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, syntax

I have been searching about this error for a couple of weeks. And I couldn't find the right answer. So I am done about that. Here is my ASP.net c# code

```
    MySqlDataAdapter cmd = new MySqlDataAdapter("select  * from haberler  order by id desc  limit 10 where kategori='anaokulu'", con);
```

and the error is :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where kategori='anaokulu'' at line 1

any help will be so helpful, just make me try something to solve this problem..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query is not well-formed. The `WHERE` clause comes before the `ORDER BY` clause.  Try this.

```
select  * from haberler where kategori='anaokulu'  order by id desc  limit 10
```

The basics of SQL statement syntax, like the ordering of clauses, are the same for most RDBMS server makes and models. The details differ a little bit.

There are plenty of online resources about this. Here's a decent one. http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Main_Page